# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://saja.smjd.ir/api/Account/login' from origin 'http://**' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I created my project on the frontend side with Angular 9 and on the backend side with asp.net.core 3 and uploaded it to the server side.
Now when I want to get a token from the server or use a token, I encounter the following error.

```
        Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://**/api/Account/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has    been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
        **/api/Account/login:1 

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://**/api/Account/login", ok: false, …}
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I'm sure the server side is handy, and works well when the backend side is local but not on the host.
The host is a Linux type, can it be a problem with the host or is it a problem with Angular? Please help me.

login.ts:

```
constructor(private Service: RegisteredUsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
  formLogin = new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
  onSubmit() {
    this.Service.postDataLogin(this.formLogin.value).subscribe(
      res => {
       consile.log(res);
      },
      err => {
       console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

RegisteredUsersService.ts:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  private urlAccount: string = "https://**/api/Account";
  postDataLogin(user): Observable<IResLogin> {
    const url = this.urlAccount + '/login';
    return this.http.post<IResLogin>(url, user);
  }
}
```

backend:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EvaluationDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            app.UseCors("ExamCors");
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();



            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("The Evaluation Project Is Running...");
            });
        }
```

In Configuaration:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ExamCors", builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

Comment: Did you [enable CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) on the back end?

Comment: What is the status code returned?

Comment: I edited the question, you can see

Comment: since you're using https, can you show the entire Configure method code?

Comment: Why do you have `AllowCredentials()` *and* `AllowAnyOrigin()`? That won't work. Have you checked any logs you might have to see if there is some error happening on the server? Have you done any troubleshooting at all?

Comment: This problem does not exist in Local, but it does exist when uploading, I updated the question and added the Configure code

Comment: **Have you checked any logs you might have to see if there is some error happening on the server?** I don't get why this post, *yet another angular/CORS post*, the same gd post we see on SO at least 5 times a day, is getting up-votes.

Comment: I don't see your "ExamCors".

Comment: when I try to post to this URI, I receive an unauthorized 401 status code. Are you using an Authorization attribute on the Account controller?

Comment: I edited and added, thanks for your help and assistance

Comment: @ phduarte :on the controller yes but the action is AllowAnonymous

Comment: Hi @Eliot, Did you try to change `builder.AllowAnyOrigin()` to `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a configuration error on the server side. For security reasons, `AllowCredentials` cannot be used together with `AllowAnyOrigin`.

Replace `AllowAnyOrigin()` with explictly the origins you need.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this but its doesn't work